# ruby on rails w/ SQLServer

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I've heard from some people that RoR doesn't marry cleanly with SQLServer. We are being pushed to use SQLServer for historical and standardization reasons but if we can push back with valid reasons we can move to another db. One person on the team wants MySql and another wants Postgres, etc. I'm trying to stay out of the religious wars and really understand what the pain point is with SQLServer.

We're running the app server on a linux box, and the database will be on a windows box and the SQLServer that we're supposed to standardize on is 2008, if those details help any...

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with such configuration but.. There are some question you should (I think so) ask yourself and team.

Is there any significant advantage for your project of using SQLServer?

If yes ... Is it so overwhelming that you are ready to face some difficulties with odbc drivers such as: http://groups.google.com/group/rails-sqlserver-adapter/browse_thread/thread/6d35d4a53ac210b2

Are you ready to host so many configurations of this boxes (linux+windows) for development, staging and production?

Do you have got professional of SQLServer in your team? (backups and administration)

If you cannot get positive answers for this questions I think SQLServer could be very hard to maintain for RoR project. Still it doesn't mean it is not possible. But sometimes you must ask yourself why you should use saw to driving nails when you have got hammer at your left.

Answer (score 0):

I am successfully using Rails (version 3 to latest) with SqlServer in production for many years.

You can use https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter which recently upgraded to support latest SqlServer/Azure for Rails 5.2.